# Wamp localhost send email

Tags: email, localhost, wamp, send

I have followed this link and here is my php code. My issue is that I have tried so many times with this and didn't receive any emails. Could you please point out what went wrong? Thank you

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

```
  if($result)
  {

  $to = $email;
  $subject = "Your comfirmation email";
  $header = "from: your name <your email>";
  $message = "Thank you for registering with us. You can now login to your account";

  if(mail($to, $subject,$header,$message))
        {
  echo 'Your Confirmation Email Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.
  <a href="login.php">Click here to Login</a>';
  }
  else
     {
  echo 'Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address.
  <a href="login.php">Click here to Register</a>';
  }
  }
```

Comment: Have a quick look at the manual. You have the parameters in the wrong order in your `mail()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have tried this if(mail($to, $subject,$message,$header)) but still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a mail server configured on your system?

Windows does not come with a mail server like *nix. The simple answer is to use a library like phpMailer, which allows you to use a gmail /yahoo /etc mail account to send you email.